# MongoDB distinct records

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I have a document of the following structure (and a lot more similar documents):

```
{
   ObjectId("54b537316483d17065eaf3e0"),
   "alternativeVendors":[
      {
         "sku":"PA10100",
         "vendor":"BUGATTI"
      },
      {
         "sku":"P984",
         "vendor":"HEPU"
      }
   ]
}
```

My goal is to retrieve a list of vendors matching a specific regex (say, /HE/).

I run the following query:

```
db.products.distinct('alternativeVendors.vendor', {'alternativeVendors.vendor' : /HE/})
```

I would expect it to find only HEPU, but instead it returns both BUGATTI and HEPU.

I understand where this comes from: the query returns documents that are matching the regex, and then all distinct vendors are returned from those documents. But I only need to find the vendors and not the documents.

Is it possible to do without doing a separate pass of filtering the data?  I am using Node.js, if you would consider application specific examples.